# decimal option in pd.read_excel() deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal-point

Until recently I used

```
pd.read_excel("afile.xslx", decimal=',')
```

with a decimal option, which allows it to parse European dates very easily.

I updated pandas to version 1.1.3 today and it doesn't accept the option "decimal = " anymore. Is this option deprecated and if so, what is a good way to import numbers that are stored as text in excel with "," as decimal point, for example "11,3" ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) ever accepted a `decimal` argument. [This github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14403) asks for it (an ongoing issue that was opened in 2016 and is still active, as of October 2020).

I think you are confused with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that still accepts `decimal` as of pandas 1.1.3.

Anyhow, with [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) you can use the `converters` argument. From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **converters**: dict, default `None`. Dict of functions for converting values
> in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels,
> values are functions that take one input argument, the Excel cell
> content, and return the transformed content.

```
def decimal_converter(value):
    try:
        return float(value.replace(',', '.'))
    except ValueError:
        return value

pd.read_excel("afile.xslx", converters={'column_name': decimal_converter})
```

Comment: thanks for the elegant solution! And: my question concerns indeed pd.read.excel() not pd.read.csv(). Astonishingly it worked as described above till my todays updates.

Comment: I confirm that in version 1.0.3 read excel uses decimal and seems they removed in 1.1.3

Comment: yes, I used it too and now I have the same error. Convert is not that easy since you have to says to which columns  you want to apply it. In my case they are too many.

Comment: The mentioned github issue has been solved in 2021 and since version 1.4 Pandas has a decimal option for `read_excel()`. Just be aware it will not convert the decimal sign in strings like `< 2,1`. It will leave these strings untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works for me is:

bd_df['col_1'] = bd_df['col_1'].str.replace(",", ".").astype(float)